# On the mechanics of reality

Tags: grammar-choice, grammar-identification

How would you say "on the mechanics of reality"
I'm not happy with my own translation but I can't quite put the finger of what im doing wrong
Help!

Answer (score 7):

If you were to use the term 'on' as you might find it in a book title, the appropriate Latin word would be 'de'. For the term 'mechanics', it has Greek roots but was used in Latin scientific discourse as [mechanica](https://www.dicolatin.com/Latin/Lemme/0/MECHANICA/index.html).

The translation of 'reality' is more difficult. One possibility is to use 'realitatis'. In more classical Latin, however, the use of "rerum" (referring to "of things") is a closer match.

Taking all these elements into account, my proposed translation is "De mechanica rerum", which is similar to Lucretius' "De natura rerum".

Comment: You described my concern to a T. Reality, as a concept, is kind of hard to translate. I was hoping it was just me and my lack of practice.

Comment: Much appreciated though.